# How to read value inside a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are two tables.

One table contains:

```
 Name    value

  A         1
  B         2
  C         3
  D         4
```

another table contains

```
 City     value

  aa        1
  bb        2,3
  cc        3
  dd        1,2,4
```

I want an output which contains:

```
 City     value   Name
  aa        1      A
  bb        2,3    B,C
  cc        3      C
  dd        1,2,4  A,B,D
```

How can i do this using cursor?

Comment: Why do you want to do this using a `CURSOR` instead of a set-based approach?

Comment: as there are huge amount of name and their respective values,so i guess it is easy to use cursor.

Comment: I think a set based approach won't be very straightforward here

Comment: still i dont solve the problem

Comment: You can use CTE and STUFF, refer a url for an issue similar to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: "still i dont solve the problem" - Sorry but SO is not "implement a solution for me kind of site." show us what you have tried and we'll help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks.  Your question really made me appreciate normal forms.

Anyhow, I am going to go out on a limb and assume you asked for a cursor-based solution because you assumed the non-normalized data could not be handled.

Once you have the function to materialize the rows into a value list, you can solve this with a simple query.

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE  dbo.NV  (Name CHAR(1), Value INT)
CREATE TABLE dbo.CV  (City varchar(88), ValueList VARCHAR(88))
```

loaded with the data you indicated.

And this SQL script:

```
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_NVList(@VList VARCHAR(MAX))  RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @VAL        VARCHAR(928)='',
        @FIDescr    VARCHAR(55)

SELECT @VAL = COALESCE(@VAL  + LTRIM(map.name),'')  + ','
FROM dbo.nv Map
WHERE CHARINDEX(','+LTRIM(STR(map.value)) + ',', ','+@VList + ',' ) > 0 

SET @VAL = SUBSTRING(@VAL,1,len(@VAL)-1)
RETURN(@VAL)
END 
GO  -- end of function

-- this generates the output, using the function to materialize the name-values
SELECT cv.* , dbo.f_NVList(cv.ValueList ) as NameList FROM dbo.CV cv;
```

producing your output:

[image]

PLEASE DON'T - but If you really need the cursor for some reason, instead of

```
SELECT cv.* , dbo.f_NVList(cv.ValueList ) as NameList FROM dbo.CV cv;
```

use this

```
OPEN BadIdea;
FETCH NEXT FROM BadIdea INTO  @C, @VList
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

     SET @NameList  = dbo.f_NVList(@Vlist)
     INSERT INTO @OUT VALUES( @C, @VLIST , @NameList )

    FETCH NEXT FROM BadIdea INTO  @C, @VList
END

CLOSE BadIdea
DEALLOCATE BadIdea

select * from @OUT ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try on this:

```
;with nv as (
select *
from (values ('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4')) a (Name, value))
, cv as (
select *
from (values ('aa', '1'), ('bb', '2,3'), ('cc', '3'), ('dd', '1,2,4')) a(City, value)
)
, cv2 as (
select cv.City
    , case when charindex(',',cv.value)>0 then LEFT(cv.value, charindex(',',cv.value)-1) else cv.value end value
    , case when charindex(',',cv.value)>0 then right(cv.value, LEN(cv.value)-len(LEFT(cv.value, charindex(',',cv.value)-1)+',')) end leftover
from cv
union all
select cv.City
    , case when charindex(',',cv.leftover)>0 then LEFT(cv.leftover, charindex(',',cv.leftover)-1) else cv.leftover end value
    , case when charindex(',',cv.leftover)>0 then right(cv.leftover, LEN(cv.leftover)-len(LEFT(cv.leftover, charindex(',',cv.leftover)-1)+',')) end leftover
from cv2 cv
where cv.leftover is not null


)
select *
    , stuff((
select ','+nv.Name
from cv2 
    join nv on nv.value=cv2.value
where cv2.City=cv.City
for xml path('')
), 1, 1, '') Name
from cv
```

With cv2 I split the values to City, with a recursive CTE. After that I calculate the new Name for each City.
I don't know how fast is on a big table, but I think it is better then cursor.

Answer (score 0):

using CROSS APPLY we will initially delimit all the values and then we can acheieve using XML path () and CTE's

```
DECLARE @Name table (name varchar(5),value int)
INSERT INTO @Name (name,value)values ('A',1),('B',2),('C',3),('D',4)
DECLARE @City table (city varchar(10),value varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @City (city,value)values ('aa','1'),('bb','2,3'),('cc','3'),('dd','1,2,4')
```

Code :

```
;with CTE AS (
SELECT A.city,  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT city,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(value, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  @City
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
 ),CTE2 AS (
 Select c.city,t.value,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(name AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @Name 
         WHERE value = c.Data
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
 from CTE C
 INNER JOIN @Name t
 ON c.Data = t.value
 )
 select DISTINCT c.city,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(value AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM CTE2 
         WHERE city = C.city
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') As Value ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(List_Output AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM CTE2 
         WHERE city = C.city
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ')As Name  from CTE2 C
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you need a function to split your comma-delimited values. Here is the [**DelimitedSplit8K**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) written by Jeff Moden and improved by the community. This is regarded as one of the fastest SQL-based string splitter.

You should also read on `FOR XML PATH('')`, a method to concatenate strings. Check this [**article**](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) by Aaron Bertrand for more information.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Table2 t2
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT  STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + Name
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Value IN(
            SELECT CAST(s.Item AS INT) FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t2.Value, ',') s
        )
        FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 1, 1, '')

)x(Name)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b522e/1/0)

---

Notes:

1. Make sure to get the latest version of the `DelimitedSplit8K`.
2. For other splitter functions, check out this [**article**](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) by Aaron Bertrand.